# architecture of storing object descriptions levels in #C project

Tags: c#, json, xml

I'm writing a simple puzzle game. The simplified wording I have a class `Level` that has certain characteristics (location of objects, the initial configuration and some parameters). I plan to do a lot of levels, eg 30. How clever to do it? Each level I has constructor parameters.

```
public Level (int a, int to, int s, int d, int e, int af);
```

Of course I can do in the code of an object of each level, and manually set all the characteristics Tipo

```
 Level Level 1 = New Level (552531, 552351, 55235531, 53253, 5153, 5151233);
 Level Level 2 = New Level (3641, 346351, 553461, 5334653, 34653, 523462);
 Level Level 3 = new level (6423, 461, 262346, 2346346, 234646, 62546);
...

 Level Level30 = new level (235, 6346, 643654, 34624634, 346346, 534626);
```

Of course, this will work for my simple project that can and will look fine, but if the designer will be more difficult, and will take arrays, strings and other objects? I have heard that you can store descriptions of the levels stored in xml and json, for example. Should I use it? Could it be convenient? Simple examples of this, or comparing ease of use. I unfortunately could not find it more convenient and that people use in such cases. I heard also about the resources in C #, I probably do not fit, because the levels of description are given more difficult.

Comment: how are you getting these level values? what do you intent to do these values? It depends on a lot of other factors as well

Comment: I generated them manually

Comment: you can write small tool that converts your hardcoded objects into json or xml file, use that tool to generate files. in your main program basically load those objects.

Comment: there somewhere sample code to do this? desirable is easier for a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use json file and parse it with [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).

levels.json

```
[{
"A": 552531,
"To": 552351,
"S": 55235531,
"D": 53253,
"E": 5153,
"AF": 5151233 },
{
"A": 3641,
"To": 346351,
"S": 553461,
"D": 5334653,
"E": 34653,
"AF": 523462
},
{
"A": 6423,
"To": 461,
"S": 262346,
"D": 2346346,
"E": 234646,
"AF": 62546
},
{
"A": 235,
"To": 6346,
"S": 643654,
"D": 34624634,
"E": 346346,
"AF": 534626
}]
```

**using..**

```
        var path = @"YOUR FILE PATH\levels.json";
        var strJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        List<Level> levels = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Level>>(strJson);
```

[image]